# Proving $n^2(n^2-1)(n^2+1)=60\lambda$ such that $\lambda\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I'm supposed to prove that **the product of three successive natural numbers the middle of which is the square of a natural number is divisible by $60$**. Here's my attempt.

**My Attempt**:
$$\text{P}=(n^2-1)n^2(n^2+1)=n(n-1)(n+1)[n(n^2+1)]$$
It is now enough to prove that $n(n^2+1)$ is divisible by $10$. But for $n=4$, $4(17)\ne10\lambda$ but for $n=4$, $\text{P}$ is $4080=60\cdot68$ which means apart from just being a multiple of $6$, $n(n-1)(n+1)$ is actually helping $n(n^2+1)$ with a $5$ to sustain divisibility by $60$.

How to tackle this? Thanks

Comment: $n(n^2+1)$ is always divisible by $2$. It is sometimes divisible by five. If it isn't, $(n-1)n(n+1)$ is divisible by five.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\frac{n^2(n^2-1)(n^2+1)}{60} = 2n\binom{n+2}5 + 2\binom{n+1}4 + \binom{n+1}3.
$$

Comment: How did you observe rewriting it as that identity?

Comment: The goal is to express the left hand side as some combination of binomial coefficients. To approach this, the first step is to split $n^2(n^2-1)(n^2+1)$ as $n^2(n^2-1)(n^2-4+5) = n^2(n^2-1)(n^2-4) + 5n^2(n^2-1)$. The first term goes to the first binomial term, and you do the rest to try to make the remaining terms as a combination of binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 5):

The product of three consecutive numbers is divisible by $3$.

If $n$ is even, then $4\mid n^2$. Otherwise $n^2-1$ and $n^2 + 1$ are both even.

Now the hard part:

\begin{array}{c|c}
n \pmod 5 & n^2 \pmod 5\\ \hline
0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
2 & 4 \\
3 & 4 \\
4 & 1
\end{array}

or, without modular notation,

\begin{array}{c|c}
n & n^2 & \text{The remainder when dividing by five}\\ \hline
5k & 25k^2 & 5(5k)\\
5k+1 & 25k^2 + 10k + 1 & 5(5k^2 + 2k) + 1 \\
5k+2 & 25k^2 + 20k + 4 & 5(5k^2 + 4k) + 4 \\
5k+3 & 25k^2 + 30k + 9 & 5(5k^2 + 6k + 1) + 4 \\
5k+4 & 25k^2 + 40k + 16 & 5(5k^2 + 8k + 3) + 1 \\
\end{array}

No matter what $n$ is, $n^2$ is either $-1, 0$, or $1 \pmod 5$.

Comment: If this is for an intro to proofs class, there should probably be more (like an explanation of how being divisible by 3, 4, and 5 is equivalent to being divisible by 60).

Answer (score 5):

Note that $n^5-n=n(n^2-1)(n^2+1)$ is divisible by $5$ by little Fermat. $n^3-n$ is likewise divisible by $3$ and either $n^2$ or $n^2-1$ is divisible by $4$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the *Chinese Remainder theorem* to show this product is congruent to $0\bmod 3, 4$ and $5$. You'll determine first what the squares  are, modulo these numbers.

*A sketch for the case of the modulus $4$*:

Every number $n\equiv 0,1,2$ or $3\: (\equiv -1)\bmod 4$. So 
$$n^2\equiv 0^2=0,\: 1^2=1, 2^2\equiv 0\quad\text{or}\quad 3^2\equiv(-1)^2=1.$$
As a conclusion, either $n^2$  or $n^2-1\equiv 0\mod 4$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with modular arithmetic. Could you suggest an alternative? Thanks @Bernard

Comment: Not really, but I can show how it works for one of the moduli. Don't forget modular arithmetic consists mainly in replacing a number with its remainder in the division by the modulus.

Comment: Could you write down the first few steps so that I can pickup from there? Thanks

Comment: I've posted one case. Is it clear enough?

Comment: Yes it is great. I'll try extending this methods to the other cases. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Note that we have $$n^2(n^2-1)(n^2+1)=n^2(n^2-1)(n^2-4)+5n^2(n^2-1)$$ and that $n^2$ is divisible by $4$ or $n^2-1$ is divisible by $8$.